# C# WinForms - Adding text to each line in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very new to `C#`. I learn best by experimentation, but of course, I will get completely stumped sometimes. I will try to explain my problem the best I can with what knowledge of the programming language I currently have.

I have been trying to create a simple tool to edit/add lines of text into a `text file`. I have done much researching, especially on this site, and all the information has been extremely helpful. My problem though, is adding text to both sides to a single line of text within a `multi-line textbox`.

So lets say I have a `textbox` with 2 existing lines; I want to add some text next to both sides of to one of one lines, and do the same to the next one. Here is an example of what the text would look like before and after a button is hit:

> **Before**
>
> is not the same as is different than
>
> **After**
>
> A is not the same as B A is different than B

The two lines in "Before" would be in textBox1 (multiline), and would be inserted to richTextBox1 as "After".

Hopefully I have explained it clearly enough, I do not know where to begin with this.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? If you share your code people will be better able to assist you.

Comment: I have not tried anything except for Alexander's suggestion. I have added a comment to his answer for further assistance as to how to do what I stated in that comment.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have accomplished what I was trying to do thanks to this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you have multiline textbox:

```
var list = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines);

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
  list[i] = "A" + list[i] + "B";
}

textBox1.Lines = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: I found that this worked the best. All I had to do was change the last line where it is "textBox1" to "richTextBox1". The only problem I have now, is that I need the lines to be added to existing text in the richTextBox as new lines. This I am not sure how to do. I greatly appreciate your help though.

Comment: Just change last line to **textBox1.Lines = textBox1.Lines.Concat(list).ToArray();**

Answer (score 2):

If you know which `index` you have to update the text, then you should be able to inset the value directly using `insert` function exposed by `string` class

***Example:***

```
        //Get the text box value
        var formatedTextboxString = this.textbox1.Text;

        formatedTextboxString = formatedTextboxString.Insert(0, "A ");

        formatedTextboxString = formatedTextboxString.Insert(21, "B");

        //Place the formated text back to the richTextBox 
        this.richTextBox1.Text = formatedTextboxString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"{0} is not the same as {1} {2} is different than {3}"
```

In textbox1. Then use:

```
textbox2.Text = String.Format(textbox1.Text, A, B, A, B);
```

Comment: You need to put your letters in quotes as they are not variables.

Comment: I actually meant in the String.Format(textbox1.Text, "A", "B", "A", "B");

Comment: I used A, B as variable not actually text

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = textBox1.Text.Split(Environment.Newline);
//then loop over each line and add whatever you want :-

        foreach (string s in arr)
    {
        //add here 
    }
```

I guess this is good enough hint to start with :)